# Uncheck other checkbox only this div

Tags: jquery

I have this script to uncheck the other checkbox for a pair of checkboxes.

How can I select only 1 set at a time? When I have multiple sets of checkboxes the script treats them all as 1 group.

http://jsfiddle.net/infatti/XpTDK/

```
  <div class="controls check-yes-no">
    <label class="checkbox inline">
      <input type="checkbox" value="option1" name="setupStewardshipReviewApproveReject"> Yes
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox inline">
      <input type="checkbox" value="option2" name="setupStewardshipReviewApproveReject"> No
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="controls check-yes-no">
    <label class="checkbox inline">
      <input type="checkbox" value="option1" name="setupStewardshipReviewApproveReject"> Yes
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox inline">
      <input type="checkbox" value="option2" name="setupStewardshipReviewApproveReject"> No
    </label>
  </div>

$('.check-yes-no input:checkbox').click(function () {
    $(".check-yes-no input[type='checkbox']").not(this).prop("checked", false); // uncheck the other checkbox when this is checked
});
```

Comment: Are you sure you shouldn't have radio buttons ? Your UI is disturbing.

Comment: sorry to disturb you. lol requirement for checkboxes to require user to make an action rather than accepting preselected radio.

Comment: you need to explain the difference of radios and check boxes to the person that made the requirements

Answer (score 0):

Technically it's not a big change :

```
$('.check-yes-no input:checkbox').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('.check-yes-no').find("input[type='checkbox']")
         .not(this).prop("checked", false); 
});
```

but as a UI, I find this disturbing : you should probably use radio buttons instead. Users don't expect checkboxes to uncheck themselves like this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're not looking for something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/XpTDK/1/

A minor edit to your code:

```
  <div class="controls check-yes-no">
    <label class="checkbox inline">
      <input type="radio" value="option1" name="name1"> Yes
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox inline">
      <input type="radio" value="option2" name="name1"> No
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="controls check-yes-no">
    <label class="checkbox inline">
      <input type="radio" value="option1" name="name2"> Yes
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox inline">
      <input type="radio" value="option2" name="name2"> No
    </label>
  </div>
```

---

> Here are the standard definitions for form controls:
>
> - Radio buttons are for lists of two or more mutually exclusive items. In other words, you can  choose only one of several
>     options—like a multiple-choice question.
>
>   - Check boxes offer a binary choice—turning the option on or off—like a true/false question.
>
>     - Groups of check boxes allow the visitor to choose any number of items from the list.
>     - Single check boxes are for stand-alone, yes/no style questions.
>
> These definitions are reasonably clear, but common mistakes continue
>   to appear on Web sites. Consider these examples culled from some
>   recent surfing:
>
> - A question followed by two radio buttons labeled Yes and No. That offers two mutually exclusive choices, but a single check box would do
>     the same thing much more efficiently.
> - A list of several check boxes, preceded by instructions to check only one item. If only one selection is allowed, use radio buttons
>     instead of check boxes.
> - A list of check boxes, with instructions to check all that apply. The instruction is redundant since the ability to check multiple
>     options is implicit in the use of check boxes instead of radio
>     buttons. Apparently, the Web builder felt that this instruction was
>     necessary to clarify that the list is an example of the normal use of
>     check boxes. This is an indication of the confusion caused by the
>     widespread misuse of check boxes where only one selection is allowed.
> - Two separate questions, related and contradictory, each with its own stand-alone check box. Related choices should be grouped together
>     with radio buttons for responses if the choices are mutually
>     exclusive. Better yet, combine the questions into one choice with a
>     single check box.

Source: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/proper-usage-of-check-boxes-and-radio-buttons/5418918